# Add chart inside list in RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm trying to add a chart control inside a list but I keep getting the error message "Unsupported Action"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. 
1. Create a report with chart inside it. Provide some parameters. 
2. Use this report as a sub-report inside the list in the main report 
3. link up the parameters in the subreport with from the main report